# Using a UIButton as an Accessory View for a UITableCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have run into an interesting bug where it appears that when you select a UITableCell it changes all of it's subviews to their highlighed state.  This includes my accessoryView which is a UIButton which obviously I only want highlighted when the user presses like a normal button.

I have a friend who went as far subclassing UIButton to override this in his app and manually managed the state for this type of behavior but that seems drastic to get what should be the expected behavior.  So, I am wondering what other solutions people have come up with for this problem.

Has anyone else had this issue?  If so, what did you do to work around it?  Any code samples as well as ideas are very welcome!

Comment: i've always used a custom button any time i wanted one in a UITableViewCell as the default image isn't incredibly pleasing to the eye in that situation, so its not really a drastic step, and is quite common.

Comment: I am not overly concerned about having to create a custom class for UIButton so much as I am that I might run into problems with my app being future proofed if/when apple makes the change that UIControl subclasses shouldn't be highlighted or that I miss some use case that will cause other odd behavior with the highlight state.  

I will go ahead and give using a UIButtonTypeCustom a try but from my understanding of the bug it seems like it would just show my custom highlighted state when i select the row instead.

Thanks for your input Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended going with a custom button on this like Jesse Recommended abd set both the highlighed and normal state to the same image.  It seemed to work well enough for what I was trying to do.  Thanks again!